# Can hydrides react with hydrocarbons? And why?

Tags: hydrocarbons, hydrogen

I have read there exist so called "magic" (super strong) acids which can provide a proton to saturated hydrocarbons, producing cation and hydrogen molecule. Can hydrides act in the same manner (pick a proton to form free hydrogen molecule)? And why?

Comment: Depends on hydride.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pKa of sodium or lithium hydride is (solvent dependent) about 35, the pKa of Butyl lithium is around 50 so clearly H- is not strong enough to tear a proton off an unactivated alkane [pKa tables here](http://www.uwindsor.ca/people/jgreen/sites/uwindsor.ca.people.jgreen/files/pka_bases.pdf)

Comment: Then again, cyclopentadiene is also a hydrocarbon, so...

Comment: Not exactly unactivated though as the cyclopentadienyl anion is aromatic

Comment: True, but there was no "unactivated" in the original question.

Comment: The OP asked about saturated hydrocarbons, which excludes cyclopentadiene,

Comment: OK, I stand corrected.